# pandas fillna is not working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but I cannot get fillna() to work on my dataframe. Here's the snippet:

```
print(featureframe.mean())
featureframe = featureframe.fillna(featureframe.mean().to_dict())
if featureframe.isnull().values.any():
    print("Still NaN in data")
    print(featureframe[featureframe.isnull().any(axis=1)])
    exit(9)
```

I have checked the first printout: none of the means are NaN, so the second line *should* fill every element that is NaN with the mean of the column and eliminate any NaNs that there are in my dataset. However, it exits in the subsequent if clause and prints quite a lot of rows that still contain NaN values.

Answer (score 1):

Does `featureframe` include any non-numeric columns that also have NaN values? `DataFrame.mean` will exclude these from the mean calculation, so no corresponding entry would result in the dictionary passed to `fillna`, meaning that the non-numeric column NaNs will remain.

If the data is all numeric, then I can say I cannot reproduce your problem. For a `DataFrame` with all numeric columns, the code you have works with no error and fills in all NaN values with the corresponding column mean. Here is an example:

```
In [62]: dfrm
Out[62]: 
          A         B         C    D
0  0.214370  0.974447  0.173714    a
1  0.944512  0.915541  0.112383    b
2       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN
3  0.412725  0.470967  0.710573    d
4  0.097110  0.799356  0.044364    e
5  0.436439  0.413927  0.747808    f
6  0.366761  0.751613  0.109822    g
7  0.909878  0.514936  0.197654    h
8  0.424923  0.993769  0.778327    i
9  0.956123  0.423588  0.126203    j

In [63]: dfrm.fillna(dfrm.mean().to_dict())
Out[63]: 
          A         B         C    D
0  0.214370  0.974447  0.173714    a
1  0.944512  0.915541  0.112383    b
2  0.529205  0.695349  0.333428  NaN
3  0.412725  0.470967  0.710573    d
4  0.097110  0.799356  0.044364    e
5  0.436439  0.413927  0.747808    f
6  0.366761  0.751613  0.109822    g
7  0.909878  0.514936  0.197654    h
8  0.424923  0.993769  0.778327    i
9  0.956123  0.423588  0.126203    j
```

Comment: Hm, I just checked whether I have non-numeric columns and I definitely don't. df.mean() also returns 53 values, which is exactly the number of columns I have. When I open my dataframe in the debugger I see the following:
index - corresponds to the labels of each row
columns - corresponds to the labels of each column
for each column label, a corresponding Series object and the values in there

After stepping through the fillna method it has definitely not filled the NaN values.
This is with Python 3 and Pandas 0.21.0

Comment: @Acrofales It sounds like it is some other code error / typo that is not reproducible from the posted code, since your original code with `fillna` works with no errors to achieve the filling pattern you desire. So it is not an error with `fillna` and it is not an error with your use of `mean` or `to_dict` in your original code. This means it probably is just some unrelated code typo / bug not represented by the posted code.

Comment: @Acrofales Just to further make certain, I created a new conda environment using the same versions of Python and Pandas that you mentioned (I tried each major version of Python 3 and also 3.6.4, with pandas 0.21.0), and I cannot reproduce your problem, If I use your exact code copy/pasted from the original question, it works as expected with no errors and no remaining NaN values when all the columns are numeric.

Comment: Well, I dunno. It is probably something about the dataframe itself, but in my workaround I literally replace the second line of the code in the question with what is in my workaround and it fixes it. I have not changed anything else in my code. Is it possible that they are np nans and not pandas nans or something?

Comment: @Acrofales pandas would treat all NaN values as the `np.NaN` value, and it even converts to `np.NaN` (the `np.float64` value) for numeric columns. For example setting a float value to `None` actually just sets it to `np.NaN`. If you can post all of the actual data, maybe we can debug whatever additional error there is. But based on your workaround code, it suggests there is no error in the data that could impact your original use of `fillna`, and that it's just some code difference in your real code vs. what you posted in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I still don't know what's wrong with fillna, but here is a workaround that worked for me:

```
for c in featureframe:
    featureframe[c] = featureframe[c].replace(np.nan, featureframe[c].mean())
```

Seems far from ideal to do it this way, but at least it fills the NaNs.